# The sum of two positive numbers is 1. The sum of their cubes is a maximum. What are the numbers?

Tags: optimization

I set this up and end up finding the minimum (the two numbers would both be $1/2$).  To find a maximum value, I could reflect the functions and use $y^3-x^3$ but I still end up finding $1/2$ as the two numbers.  It does make sense that two two values to produce a max would be 0 and 1 but I can't figure out how to set up the problem from the start.  What I have is...

$x+y=1 \\
x^3 + y^3 = max$

Subsitution...

$x^3 - (1-x)^3 = max \\
x^3 - 1 + 3x - 3x^2 + x^3 = max \\
2x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1 = max \\
6x^2 - 6x + 3 = 0 \\
x = 1/2 \text{ which makes }y = 1/2 \\
$

That is where my issue is.  How do I set it up to find the sum of the cubes to be a max?

Comment: Are you sure the problem requires both numbers to positive, rather than nonnegative? There isn't actually a maximum if both are required to be positive.

Comment: I agree!  I am proofing someone's calculus work and I think there was a typo in the original question.  I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss something obvious.  Someone else suggested to define x>y then as x increases from 1/2 towards one, b would decrease from 1/2 towards 0.  But that seems to not be mathematically sound.

Comment: The substitution seems to flip the sign: from $x^3+y^3$ to $x^3-(..)^3$.

Comment: A maximum *of what*? Maximum of $x^3 + y^3$? Okay, over what interval, if any?

Comment: @user147485 you can say "without loss of generality" that $x \ge y$ because those are simply names.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $x^3 +(1-x)^3 = max$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a function defined on a closed interval. The maximum and minimum are found where the derivative is zero, **or at the boundaries of the interval**.

You can take derivative, but you also need to check for the case $x=0$ and $x=1$. By the way your original question does not have an answer. I suppose you should mean "nonnegative".

Comment: I would say it's not clear over what interval the maximum is. The question doesn't seem to specify.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative, then $x$ is in the closed interval $[0,1]$. Even if the question is unclear, the attempted solution made it clearer.

Comment: Isn't an unqualified maximum usually understood to be over the maximum value over for any member of the domain (and codomain) of the function, though? $x^3 + y^3$ accepts many more values of $x$ and $y$ than just $[0, 1]$.

Comment: The problem imposes restriction on the value that $x$ and $y$ can take. Without such restrictions it would be indeed as you say.

Comment: Also, as dxiv points out below, the question restricts the values to $(0,1]$, not $[0,1]$.

Comment: No. The original question restricts the values to $(0,1)$. So there is not a maximum. I stated that in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\;1=(a+b)^3 = a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b) \implies a^3+b^3 \le 1\,$.

However, with $\,a, b \gt 0\,$ strictly positive, the maximum does not exist, since for $\,a \to 0$ and $b=1-a \to 1\,$ the sum $a^3+b^3$ can get arbitrarily close to $1$, but not equal $1$. If you allow for non-negative $a,b \color{red}{\ge} 0$, instead, then the maximum is $1$ and is attained for $\{a,b\}=\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 4):

You should draw the graph of the cubic function you found for $x$ after your substitution. Then you'll see what's going on.

You can't find maxima or minima by blindly finding out where a derivative vanishes. You have to think about what is going on at the ends of the domain too.

In this case there really is no maximum, because you're requiring positive $x$ and $y$ so can't use $0$. You can get as close to a maximum value of $1$ as you wish, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at first:
$$x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$$
Since you want to maximize this and $x+y=1$, we get that:
$$x^3+y^3=x^2-xy+y^2$$
Now, you can see the above as a quadratic with respect to $x$ - a parabola, and calculate:
$$\Delta=y^2-4y^2=-3y^2<0$$
So, this parabola attains its minimum value - it has a positive leading coefficient - at $x_0=\frac{y}{2}$ and it maximum value on the boundaries of the interval that $x$ belong to. In our case, since we have $x\in(0,1)$, it is clear that this parabola cannot have a maximum value. However, if we let - as proposed by many - $x,y\in[0,1]$, we see that the so wanted maximum value can be attained for:
$$x=0,y=1$$
or, symmetrically, for $$x=1,y=0$$

Alternatively, you can substitute $y=1-x$ in the above quadratic and get that:
$$x^3+y^3=x^2-x(1-x)+(1-x)^2=x^2-x+x^2+x^2-2x+1=3x^2-3x+1$$
which, again has a global minimum and attains its maximum value either on $0$ or $1$ - actually, exactly on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$ and $x+y=1$, then $y=1-x$ and $0 \le x \le 1$

So $x^3+y^3=x^3 + (1-x)^3 = 3x^2-3x+1$. This is a parabola with axis of symmetry, and minimum, at $x = \frac 12$. It follow that the max values will be at $x=0$ and $x=1$.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your answer gives the MINIMUM. As explained above, the diff is not zero at the ends of the range, where the answer is. So that answer is (1-€)x€.

(€=epsilon)